# How to add link without ruining transition CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, transition

how would i go about so that when a user clicks on an image it takes them to another page although without ruining the transition as everything ive tried works but removes the transition or makes the one of the images dissapear

html

```
<div class="box1"> 
<img class="bottom" src="images/eventbox2.png"/>
<img class="top" src="images/eventbox.png"/>
</div>
```

css

```
.box1 {
  width:430px;
  height:450px;
}


#imagetrans {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#imagetrans img.top:hover,
#container > div img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#imagetrans img,
#container > div img {
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried adding "a" to the CSS

```
#imagetrans img,
#container > div img a {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```